# Problems getting NOIR camera board working with OpenCV2

Tags: opencv, raspicam

I'm trying to get opencv2 working on a Raspberry PI with a NOIR camera module. As I understand it Opencv doesn't work natively with the camera module; so I'm following [this link](https://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-2-compilation/) to try and get it working.

I've installed Opencv on the PI, and I think thats working, but just need it to work with the camera.

When I get to step 3 in the above link, which suggests I navigate to the /opt/vc folder and type:

```
sed -i ‘s/if (DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/g’ makefiles/cmake/arm-linux.cmake
```

I get the error message:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

1) Could someone please explain what the above command does?

2) Why might I get this error?

3) Does the folder structure matter? When I downloaded the source files from github, it was in the format **userland-master/userland-master/then_all_the_files** so I took **all_the_files** and placed them in the **/opt/vc/** folder.

Comment: Now you have it solved I can explain what the command does. sed the Stream EDitor takes the input from makefiles/cmake/arm-linux.cmake and applies the substitution command (thats the "s" in front of the "/"). This uses everything up until the second "/" as the FIND and everything after that "/" until the last "/" as the REPLACE (please note that these are treated as regular expressions). The last "g" is the global flag indicating that all occurrences and not just the first one found on each line are replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear!

I didn't read the comments, the first comment suggested i chainge the type of quotation marks, and bingo it worked, Sorry!

This worked:

```
sudo sed -i 's/if (DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/g' makefiles/cmake/arm-linux.cmake
```

Comment: It's pretty daft that it was posted that way to start with.  The shell interprets backticks as [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).